# How can I make my "IF" statement accept more than 3 arguments?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to create a hashtag checker in which someone will type in some values and it will let them know if they should use the hashtag or not based on the number of followers they have and the amount of post's the hashtag has. Unfortunately, Google sheets are not allowing me to put multiple values in the "IF" statement. Please see below and let me know where I am going wrong.

```
=IF(AND(B2<1001, B2>1), IF(C7<100000, C7>1000), "Use", "Don't Use")
```

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=IF((B2<1001)*(B2>1), IF((C7<100000)*(C7>1000), "Use", "Don't Use"), )
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need multiple if's. You are only checking if all 4 things are true. Happily, AND takes multiple arguments. Thus:

```
=IF(AND(B2<1001, B2>1, C7<100000, C7>1000), "Use", "Don't Use")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
=IF(AND(B2<1001, B2>1, C7<100000, C7>1000), "Use", "Don't Use")
```